# Windows 10 Update Failing On Previous WSUS Client

Tags: wsus, windows-10

I previously had client computers (Windows 7) configured for using WSUS.  When we went to take the Windows 10 upgrades, we were told that Windows Server Update Service is incompatible with Windows 10 and should be manually removed.  We hadn't been making any substantial use of WSUS, so I uninstalled the role from our 2012 server, however the installer on the clients is still reporting the WSUS agent as installed.

How can I manually remove the WSUS alterations to the Windows Update agent in order to get the Windows 10 upgrade working?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to change Group Policy settings; that's usually how clients are pointed at the WSUS server in the first place, instead of Microsoft for updates.

Edit GP and look in **Comp Config -> Admin Temp -> Win Comp -> Win Update**.  Start by making sure *Specify Intranet...* is disabled.  Disabled == clients will look to MS for updates.

If GP isn't specifying an intranet updates server, then perhaps someone manually configured the clients' reg keys.  Check a client's **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate** to confirm.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these is set and I'm still getting the error... not sure what it is actually checking for to get the error.  Wish it gave more details.  Interestingly, another computer on the same domain had no issues.

Comment: I think you need to check windowsupdate.log man...not sure if I fully understand the problem anymore.

Comment: That's probably not a bad idea.  Hopefully it includes more details about the failure.  I hate how "user friendly" errors have become rather than saying what the actual problems are.  Yeah, the logs are still often better, but it's a bit of a hassle to go digging for them and then finding the right spot in them.

Answer (score 0):

So I did some digging and identified the location that the config files for the upgrade appraiser are located (in $windows.~BT/sources/Panther).  Turns out it was looking at the wsussetup.exe file that was still hanging around in Program Files/System Center Essentials 2007/ because the uninstall from ages past didn't bother to actually remove the installer.  Cleaned up the folder (after verifying it wasn't installed) and all is well...